# Future-in-the-past

Tags: grammaticality

Was ist richtig:

> 1. Sie haben mir versprochen, dass ich persönliche Betreuung haben **werde.**
> 2. Sie haben mir versprochen, dass ich persönliche Betreuung haben **würde.**

Und

> 1. In Ihrer Anzeige stand, dass ich eine persönliche E-Mail Adresse **haben werde.**
> 2. In Ihrer Anzeige stand, dass ich eine persönliche E-Mail Adresse **hätte.**

Future in the past (Konjunktiv II) ?

Comment: Was ist der Sinn hinter dem zweiten Satz ? Wäre gut zu wissen, weil die letzten beide Sätze grammatikalisch stimmen würden.

Comment: You need to explain what your problem is. All of these sentences are correct. You seem to have a question relating to *werden*, *würde* and Konjunktiv II but it is impossible to guess what the question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A)

> 1. Sie haben mir versprochen, dass ich persönliche Betreung haben werde.

Bezieht sich auf eine Zusage. Wo bleibt die jetzt? Wann  kommt sie? Futurum, Indikativ

> 2. Sie haben mir versprochen, dass ich persönliche Betreuung haben würde.

Vorwurf gegen ein leeres Versprechen. Offenbar hat die eine Seite eine Bedingung nicht erfüllt. Futurum, Konjunktiv.

B)

> 1.In Ihrer Anzeige stand, dass ich eine persönliche E-Mail
>    Adresse haben werde.

Wie oben (A1): Indikativ im Futurum

> 2.In Ihrer Anzeige stand, dass ich eine persönliche E-Mail Adresse hätte.

hiesse es: "haben würde" wäre es dasselbe wie im ersten Beispiel (A2).

So aber, mit *hätte* ist die indirekte Rede in der Gegenwart gemeint.

Das hiesse, dass da schon ein e-mail account eingerichtet worden sein sollte, wo z.B nur noch ein persönliches Passwort abgeändert werden müsste. In der mailbox könnten schon wichtige Informationen oder mails stecken, was aber offenbar nicht zutrifft.  Jedenfalls kann der neue Mitarbeiter keine e-mail Adresse auf seinen Namen in seinen Arbeitsunterlagen finden. Vielleicht hat er nicht einmal Internet in seinem Büro!

Die beiden ersten Sätzen (A1,B1) kommen im Kleid einer Erinnerung bzw. der Einforderung einer Zusage daher (Indikativ)

In den beiden anderen (A2,B2,) hört man eine Beschwerde  gegen die Nichteinhaltung einer  Abmachung heraus. (Konjunktiv)

Comment: Nö, "Da stand, dass ich hätte" ist offensichtlich nicht "... dass ich gehabt hätte". Also wäre das formal richtig, in irgendeiner Interpretation auf die Gegenwart bezogen. Aber praktisch würde ein Hörer den Relativsatz in die Zeit des Hauptsatzes verorten, das stimmt schon.